# What is the ip or url used by android GPS sensor to detect location?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-gps

I'm creating android application on custom handheld device and I'm using vpn service secure connection to our servers, I have a problem that vpn server blocks all urls except one I specify and thus gps location stopped working, what url or ip should I exclude to get gps works with vpn

Comment: I'm quite sure GPS is irrelevant to URLs, perhaps you are failing to get a location because it uses internet in order to detect antennas nearby and calculate it's location but you can still set your phone to rely on it's own GPS, it's less accurate and takes bit more time but you should be able to get locations from that.

Comment: but as GPS requires internet to work, it must be calling some ip address, location stopped working only when I connected through vpn, notice that vpn is not set on phone, rather it's on internet service provider level

Comment: I know, but then again, I don't think it's addressing a specific URL for it's data rather than "scanning" the network in some manner to find known locations to generate it's own location from. Considering you are in a VPN all those are blocked, meaning you can't "know" any locations near you to calculate your location from. That's just my opinion tho

Comment: GPS does NOT require internet.

Comment: @Dan Baruch, `it's own GPS, it's less accurate `??? The only thing that is accurate is the gps receiver.

Comment: @blackapps I meant that if you turn on your device GPS you can (or at least used to) set it to either use WiFi and bluetooth for more accurate location or rely only on the device's GPS sensor. Both works of course and both are accurate, it's just using the Wifi and bluetooth is more accurate, at least that's how I remember it

Comment: @Dan Baruch, a gps chip does not use internet, wifi or bluetooth to begin with. The Android/Google code to determine location can use different mechanisms. The only one that is accurate is gps.